# Big O notation of string permutation in Python

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, permutation, complexity-theory

```
def permutation(str): #str = string input

    if len(str) == 0:

        return [""]

    result = []

    for i, char in enumerate(str):

        for p in permutation(str[:i] + str[i + 1 :]):

            result.append(char + p)

    return result
```

I am confused in asymptotic analysis (time complexity) in this code does it have an O(n!) or O(n*n!) because the recursive call is in the loop. I am still confused does the big O notation only based on regular notation like logarithmic, linear, quadratic, exponential, factorial, etc. Or could beyond that like a combination not only based on the regular notation

I already tried to calculate it and see some explanation in youtube but still couldn't understand well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the time complexity of the function be `T(n)`, where `n` is the length of the input string.

For the case where `n` is not 0, we need to consider the following parts:

1. For the outer loop, it needs to be repeated `n` times.
2. For the outer loop body, the time complexity of each recursive call is `T(n - 1)`. (I omitted the `O(n)` time complexity of constructing the input, considering that `T(n - 1)` is at least `(n - 1)!`, which should not affect the results.)
3. For inner loop, since the output size of the permutation is `n!`, it needs to be repeated `(n - 1)!` times (the input length for recursive calls is `n - 1`).
4. For the inner loop body, due to the length of `p` being `n - 1`, the time complexity of `char + p` is `O(n)`.

In summary, we can conclude that:

```
T(n) = n * (T(n - 1) + O(n) * (n - 1)!)
     = n * T(n - 1) + n * O(n!)
     = n * ((n - 1) * T(n - 2) + (n - 1) * O((n - 1)!)) + n * O(n!)
     = n * (n - 1) * T(n - 2) + (n - 1) * O(n!) + n * O(n!)
     ...
     = n! * T(0) + 1 * O(n!) + 2 * O(n!) + ... + n * O(n!)
     = O(n!) + (1 + 2 + ... + n) * O(n!)
     = O((1/2 * n**2 + 1/2 * n + 1) * n!)
     = O(n**2 * n!)
```

Comment: Matches my [experiment](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TU9BDoIwELz3FXukFRQ8qQm_8AME29CEbsl2OfAWL1z0Tx78i8ViZJKdZDY7s5n7c5i48zjPj5FNcXq9DXkHruEOrBs8MZimZU-26cW6CFMAEWkfNJNuRwrWY2-d5ey8QApx0wauGcqLgAhrAKGuoUxyAWkeCaESG4GgIIuuopKw-79NCwUYc42neGajsczjJFpjB7LIGebfx3DYBiwSlTrKVHLt-uv8AQ).

Comment: so the big o of an algorithm is indeed cloud go beyond n! right? theres no need to simplify it as n!

Comment: @AlvalenShafel I have tried to search for some information but have not seen the practice of omitting polynomials when multiplying polynomials with `n!`. I think it should not be simplified.

Comment: @MechanicPig ohh okay i think i understand that well, thank you for helping :D

Comment: @AlvalenShafel There's not just no "need" to simplify it like that, it would be **wrong**. This **isn't** in O(n!).